# Eclipse with Spring Tools 4 gives a warning on public @Bean methods

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I have just upgraded Eclipse to version 2023-09 and installed Spring Tools 4 from the marketplace.  Now, in projects using Spring Boot 2.7.18, I get a lot of warnings because I have the `public` modifier on `@Bean` methods.  Is it a bad practice?  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76454349/685806) says that the method visibility does not affect the bean's visibility and, in facts, I have not found anything about access modifiers of `@Bean` methods in Spring docs and [this manual page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/java/basic-concepts.html) has an example with a public `@Bean` method.  So why should I change it?  Can this note be disabled?

**Update:** added some screen-shots.  Now I see that in the Properties dialog it has "Info" severity but in the "Markers" view it is under a warning icon due to the presence of other messages.  It has also a quick fix.

[image: Screen-shot1]

[image: Screen-shot1]

[image: Screen-shot2]

Comment: What is the exact warning message?

Comment: @howlger, It says just `public '@Bean' method` and it disappears if I remove the `public` modifier.  It also provides a quick fix to remove the modifier from the method or from the file or from the project.

Comment: In the "Markers" view it appears in the "Spring Boot" group.

Comment: Please copy the whole line from the _Problems_ view, including the _Type_. (I did not downvote the question nor did I vote to close it, but I would recommend to include the exact warning message into the question and more details about the `@Bean` annotation used here.)

Comment: @howgler, added screen-shots.  I assumed that it is common with this version of Eclipse/STS, isn't it?

Comment: Please copy **the whole line** from the Problems view.

Comment: @nitind, I have already answered my question, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: under "Window/Preferences/Spring/Validation/Boot 2.x Best Practices & Optimizations" there is a "Public '@Bean' method" option that you can set to "Ignore".  The tooltip says:

> Public modifier on '@Bean' method. They no longer have to be public
> visibility to be usable by Spring.

Comment: Correct, this is part of the new validations that give you hints and information about changing and improving your Spring usage in the source code. There are a number of those validations in place and you can enable/disable them in the preferences. If you come across a situation where the preference is configured as "info", but the marker appears in the problems view as a warning, please file a bug at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues. And if you find validations to show up as false positives, please let us know as well.